# Detect if Vim will exit from inside an autocmd

Tags: vim

I have a `BufWritePost` autocmd that I want to run every time when a buffer is written *but not* when Vim is about to exit.

The variable `v:dying` does not really help as it only indicates if Vim exists due to a signal but I also want to detect normal shutdown. So I am looking for some thing along the lines of

```
au BufWritePost * if ! s:do_we_quit() | Neomake | endif
```

but as of now I have no idea how to write the `s:do_we_quit()` test.

**Context:**
The autocmd just calls `:Neomake` to run syntax checks and linters on my files and load them into the quickfix/location list. But that does obviously only make sense on `:w` and not on `:wq`. Normally `Neomake` works asynchronously but on exit it seems to me that vim hangs and waits for `Neomake` and then somehow it ends up in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `QuitPre`:

```
let s:quitting = 0
autocmd QuitPre      * let s:quitting = 1
autocmd BufWritePost * if ! s:quitting | Neomake endif
```

This assumes you're running a decently recent Vim (`QuitPre` was added in Vim 7.3.544).

You should probably post a bug report about the infinite loop.

Comment: I was hoping for a less hancrafted version but I think it will do.

Comment: @Lucas Not sure what you mean by "handcrafted".  This is precisely the intended use of `QuitPre`.

Comment: I meant that the solution is dependent on my config (I have to set up the `QuitPre` autocmd). I was hoping for something like `v:quitting` analougus to `v:dying` and `v:vim_did_enter` which would make my `BufWritePost` autocmd only dependent on vim internals. Now I have to trust that `QuitPre` is triggered before `Bufwritepost` on `:wq`. I will accep the answer nontheless, also seeing that it is the best one available ;)

Comment: Like I said, this is how you're supposed to do it.  `QuitPre` is guaranteed to run before any `BufWritePost`.  A hypothetical `v:quitting` would be useless for that purpose, since technically at that point Vim is not quitting yet.  Yes, that isn't terribly coherent, but that's how Vim is. Which bit is useful for what is described in some detail in the manual, just not all in the same place, you have to hunt for it.

Comment: I came across a problem b/c `s:quitting == 1` if I close one of several windows but then `Neomake` will not run on the next `:w`. More details in the answer below.

Comment: Hmm.  You might need to keep track of quit state [per buffer](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/blob/6fb14d624b6081459360fdbba743f82cf84c8f92/plugin/syntastic.vim#L372).

Answer (score 0):

Based on Sato's answer I came up with this:

```
let s:quitting = 0
autocmd BufWritePost *
    \ if ! s:quitting                             |
    \   Neomake                                   |
    \ elseif tabpagenr('$') > 1 || winnr('$') > 1 |
    \   let s:quitting = 0                        |
    \ endif
autocmd QuitPre * let s:quitting = 1
```

- `s:quitting` has to be reset after closing a window, otherwise `Neomake` will not run on the next `:w` anywhere.
- I can not check the window number in `QuitPre` as it could be anything if I `:wqa`
- also I really don't want to run `Neomake` if I close a window as I might close all further windows shortly after (before `Neomake` is finished) and then Neovim will still hang

#### Update 1

NeoVim  also provides `v:exiting` but that is not yet set at the time `BufWritePost` is triggered.

#### Update 2

Neomake now provides a command `NeomakeCancelJobs` so the original problem is solved by force canceling all running jobs in `VimLeave`:

```
augroup LucNeoMake
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWritePost * Neomake
  autocmd VimLeave * NeomakeCancelJobs
augroup END
```

(This is a solution to my original problem but not the the question.)